# How do I select only the area inside contours?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm implementing a Foreground Extraction algorithm in Python which creates a mask and contours of the foreground of the image.

However, I'm working with SVS files (tif files with less properties) and after extracting the foreground and I still need to tile it because my image has gigapixel resolution. I'm using openCV to handle these images.

This is my `getContours` function:

```
def getContours(oslIm, level=2):
    """
    Loads the requested level from oslIm and returns identified contours in the slide.
    :param oslIm: openslide image
    :param level: level from which to load the data (usually 2)
    :return: contours
    """

    image_array = np.asarray(oslIm.read_region((1, 1), level, oslIm.level_dimensions[level]), dtype=np.uint8)
    image = image_array[:, :, 0:3]
    mask = segment(image)
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    return contours
```

I read my image at the desired level, I extract the mask of the foreground and then the contours.

This is the process:

**Input Image:**

[image]

**Mask:**

[image]

**Final Image**:

[image]

Everything is good, I have the contours and the final image. 
But as I said before I want to *crop* my image so I can apply my

```
sample_and_store_patches_by_row(
        file_name,
        pixel_overlap,
        patch_size=512,
        level=17,
)
```

and tile my image in 512x512 images. For that I need to get inside the contours and tile the whats inside of it.

I'm struggling with this for days, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: So you want to iterate inside the contour row by row ?

Comment: I want to do something like this:
original_image > generate mask > get contours
oritinal_image * contours = image_to_tile
generate_patches(image_to_tile)

Comment: Please explain this `image_to_tile` functionality? What is the expected output ?

Comment: image_to_tile is the original image without the background. I want to tile the foreground of the original svs image

Comment: Can you please provide sample output? I am really unable to get your expected output here. Do you want the background to be white instead of black as in current output ?